# How to find and install a missing class in wildfly 25

Tags: oracle, jdbc, wildfly-25

I'm trying to configure a wildfly/jboss server using kerberos for an oracle datasource (ojdbc8).
The kerberos part is working properly however, when reaching the oracle listener i'm getting an exception in wildfly:

```
2023-04-12 19:07:19,152 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject] (management-handler-thread - 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection

(...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.security.jgss.ExtendedGSSContext from [Module "oracle.driver" from local module loader @53f48368 (finder: local module finder @24d4d7c9 (roots: /opt/wildfly-25.0.1.Final/modules,/opt/wildfly-25.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

I was not able to find that class in the wildfly folder tree and i don't know where to find/download that class. Note that i have a very little knowledge of java

From my understanding java comes with some "native" class so i tried to install different java 11 builds (oracle, amazon, openjdk) and performed "java -verbose" to identify that package/module. However i had no success. I find one file in my jboss tree that reference that package/module :

/opt/wildfly-25.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/sun/jdk/main/module.xml

```
<module name="sun.jdk" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="deprecated"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <!-- currently jboss modules has not way of importing services from
        classes.jar so we duplicate them here -->
        <resource-root path="service-loader-resources"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="sun.scripting" export="true"/>
        <system export="true">
            <paths>

                <!-- See below for replacement modules -->

                <!-- Internal to java.base -->

                <path name="com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl"/>
                <path name="com/sun/crypto/provider"/>
                <path name="sun/security/action"/>

(...)

                <!-- Module jdk.security.jgss -->

                <path name="com/sun/security/jgss"/>

(...)
```

Any idea how to solve the situation?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you install the Oracle driver?

Comment: What version of Java is WildFly running on?  What version of Oracle DB are you trying to connect to? Do you have a specific reason for wanting to use Kerberos here?

Comment: I tried to run wildfly with java build JDK 11,  Coretto and openjdk 11. Oracle DB is 19. I believe oracle driver was installed properly since it works without kerberos. The ojdbc.jar was put in /opt/wildfly-25.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/oracle/driver/main/ojdbc11-21.6.0.0.1.jar. A module.xml was create in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solve the issue by myself,

I have edited the jdbc module.xml file to add the "sun.jdk" module as dependency:

```
cat /opt/wildfly-25.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main/module.xml

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc11.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="sun.jdk"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I don't know why this dependency is not described
Afterward i was able to connect successfully

```
/opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KerberosDS:test-connection-in-pool'
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true]
}
```